# Preview and Formatting Tool not showing on page

Tags: bug, formatting, markdown-preview

Only on electronics.stackexchange.com is the post preview below my text always empty, and the formatting tool is not shown at all. However here on *meta*.electronics.stackexchange.com it is working just fine. All other stack exchanges work fine.

The issue persists in the latest versions of Firefox And Chrome as of today.  Thus I cannot think of what could cause such a thing.

Comment: Does it work properly when you open the site in a "private" browser window?